# PHP MySQL table linking

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

When I give my print my results from my table, the id for the student appears as an id for another table that it is linked to, not the name of the student.

The results which I get from the website;

*Connected successfully*

*id: 1 - Student: 1 - Time: 60 - Date: 2017-12-28 - Notes: First test*

*id: 2 - Student: 2 - Time: 43 - Date: 2018-01-22 - Notes: Second Test*

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "timedrun";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>
<br>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, student, time, date, notes FROM times";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Student: " . $row["student"]. " - Time: " . $row["time"]. " - Date: " .$row["date"]. " - Notes: " .$row["notes"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the export from the database called "times"

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 04, 2018 at 01:40 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `timedrun`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `times`
--

CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `times`
--

INSERT INTO `times` (`ID`, `student`, `time`, `date`, `notes`) VALUES
(1, 1, 60, '2017-12-28', 'First test'),
(2, 2, 43, '2018-01-22', 'Second Test'),
(3, 3, 75, '2018-01-12', 'Thrid Test');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `times`
--
ALTER TABLE `times`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `student` (`student`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `times`
--
ALTER TABLE `times`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `times`
--
ALTER TABLE `times`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `times_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`student`) REFERENCES `students` (`ID`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

This is the export from the database called "students"

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 04, 2018 at 01:42 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `timedrun`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearGroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `house` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `students`
--

INSERT INTO `students` (`ID`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `yearGroup`, `house`) VALUES
(1, 'Harold', 'Jones', 'E', 'K'),
(2, 'Joe', 'Blogs', 'D', 'K'),
(3, 'Cliff', 'Kloff', 'D', 'Tu');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use Inner join :

```
$sql = "select A.firstname, A.lastname, A.time, A.date, A.notes from times B,students A WHERE B.student/ID = A.ID;";
```

Try learning basic command first here are  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am getting an error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\timedRun\viewTimes.php on line 21
0 results ". Do you know what the cause of this is?

Comment: can u please share your code what you have tried exact

Comment: <?php
$sql = "select A.firstname, A.lastname, A.time, A.date, A.notes from times B,students A WHERE B.student/ID = A.ID;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Student: " . $row["student"]. " - Time: " . $row["time"]. " - Date: " .$row["date"]. " - Notes: " .$row["notes"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: In Where condition give B.NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE_COLUMN_NAME = A.MATCHING_COLUMN_NAME.    student/id is I wrote for column name based on what you are matching either student or id

Answer (score -1):

If you want the names of the students you need to change your php code from:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, student, time, date, notes FROM times";
```

to

```
$sql = "select b.firstname, b.lastname, a.time, a.date, a.notes from times a join students b on a.student = b.id;";
```

If you are going to use a relational database, such as MySQL, it's worth learning how they work and how to use SQL.  This can be very rewarding and isn't terribly difficult.  If you can learn php then you can learn SQL.  Here's [one place you could start](http://www.thedatastudio.net/relational_databases_for_agile_developers_the_book.htm).